# Maximum documents in one mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

What will be the maximum number of documents we can store in one mongodb collection?
I have one million documents with around 100 fields to insert into one collection. So, is it good to use one collection or should I go for multiple collections?

Comment: All relevant things doccumented in the manual as [MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/). If it's not in there then it's not a limit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unless you create a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), there is **no limit to the number of documents in a collection**.

There is a 16MB limit to the [size of a document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) (use `gridfs` in this situation) and limits in the storage engine for the [size of the database and data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#data).

If your documents do not exceed 16MB, then having 1 million of them will ***not*** be problematic for the mongodb storage engine limits.

Comment: what is document size is within 2MB but exceeds 1 million, how many documents I can store, can I store over a billion?

Comment: @AkshayNaik yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can store more than a billion. The better your server hardware, the better the MongoDB performance.